# Matching two array key and combine it's value with google app script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I have two formatted array as below code, and I would like to match the id and get the matched id value of size and stock

I have the code from github as below but can not get it to work

```
var arraysize = []; 
var arraycode = []; 
var code = '{id:'+stock[i][1] +',stock:'+ stock[i][4]+'}'; 
var size = '{id:'+tomatchcode+',size:'+tomatchsize+'}'; 
arraycode[i] = code;
arraysize[i] = size; 
Logger.log(arraysize); 
Logger.log(arraycode);

[19-08-29 10:32:35:003 ICT] [{id:59,size:36}, {id:123,size:37}, {id:62,size:38}, {id:63,size:39}, {id:64,size:40}]
[19-08-29 10:32:35:003 ICT] [{id:63,stock:17}, {id:123,stock:16}, {id:59,stock:10}, {id:64,stock:12}, {id:62,stock:14}]

//both array id value in random position but have same value

var matcharray =checkArrayForMatches(arraycode,arraysize)

function checkArrayForMatches(array,properties){
    var returnArray = [];
    if (Array.isArray(array[0])){
      for (var i = 0,x = array.length;i<x;i++){
        var row = array[i];
        var match = true;
        for (var j in properties){
          if (properties[j] !== row[j]){
            match = false;
          }
        }
        if (match) {returnArray.push(i)};
      }
    } else if (typeof array[0] == 'object'){
      for (var i = 0,x = array.length;i<x;i++){
        var obj = array[i];
        var match = true;
        for (var j in properties){
          if (obj[j] !== properties[j]){
            match = false;
          }
        }
        if (match) {returnArray.push(i)};
      }
    }
    return returnArray;
  }
```

The above function not returning any value. I would like it to returning array like this which contain size value following by stock value [{36,10}, {37,16}, {38,13}, {39,17}, {40,12}]
As you can see each returned value have a matching id.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're creating a string here: `var code = '{id:'+stock[i][1] +',stock:'+ stock[i][4]+'}';`. You should create a object: `var code = {id: stock[i][1] ,stock:stock[i][4]};`

Comment: Hi @TheMaster, thank you for your help, it work perfectly now :)

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Flow:

- Create a hashtable of `id:stock`
- Use `Array.map` to retrieve `stock` from hash table using `id` of `arraysize`

#### Snippet:

```js
var arraysize =  [{ id: 59, size: 36}, { id: 123, size: 37}, { id: 62, size: 38}, { id: 63, size: 39}, { id: 64, size: 40}];
var arraycode = [{ id: 63, stock: 17}, { id: 123, stock: 16}, { id: 59, stock: 10}, { id: 64, stock: 12}, { id: 62, stock: 13}];
var arrayCodeObj = {};
arraycode.forEach(function(obj){arrayCodeObj[obj.id]=obj.stock});//create hash table
var arr2d = arraysize.map(function(obj){ return [obj.size, arrayCodeObj[obj.id]]})
console.log(arr2d)
console.log(arrayCodeObj)
```

Comment: Hi @TheMaster, I tested your code and work perfectly, how ever when I attached to my code it return null, I have edited my code to show how I get the var arraysize and var arraycode.
The logger log returned exactly same as per var arraysize and var arraycode in your code, but strange it return null using your code for both Logger.log(arr2d) Logger.log(arrayCodeObj)*/
'[19-08-29 10:32:35:004 ICT] [[null, null], [null, null], [null, null], [null, null], [null, null]]'
'[19-08-29 10:32:35:004 ICT] {undefined=null}'

Comment: Not a solution to the original request, but an interesting alternative that may help someone: once you have the hash table, you can insert it into the original array, like this: **arraysize.forEach(function(obj) { if (arrayCodeObj[obj.id])  obj.stock = arrayCodeObj[obj.id]; } );**